# Google Cloud Storage Python Client Library: get_bucket() not retrieving pre-existing bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-api-python-client

I have a pre-existing bucket `test_bucket`. I am trying to use the python client library to get the bucket with the `get_bucket()` method. It straight up isn't working.

Here is my code.

```
from google.cloud import storage
storage_client = storage.Client()

try:
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("test_bucket")
except google.cloud.exceptions.NotFound:
    logger.info("not found, sorry")
```

To be clear, the instantiation of the `storage_client` variable is working fine and dandy (can print it). But for whatever reason the `storage_client.get_bucket("test_bucket")` isn't retrieving the bucket or throwing any errors what-so-ever. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Is 'test-object' really the name of the bucket? It sounds like an object name...  And as of this moment, there is no bucket called 'test-object', as confirmed by running gsutil ls gs://test-object

Comment: @MikeSchwartz Just updated. test_bucket is the "bucket". I have many objects inside test_bucket

Comment: Could you provide the stack trace of the exception?